# ¿Cómo enviar un correo que el mensaje lleve un foreach?

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, email, foreach

Muy buenas noches comunidad, tengo un pequeño error y necesito ayuda para solucionarlo.

Necesito realizar que al momento de realizar una compra un cliente de algún producto, el cliente reciba un correo de los productos que compró, lo estoy realizando con codeigniter php, aqui pego el código. Me funciona perfectamente con un solo producto, pero si son varios solo me envia el primer producto.

```
public function compra($correo,$idventa){

    $detalle = $this->getDetalle($idventa);
    $venta = $this->db->get_where('venta',['id' =>$idventa]);
    // $cambio = $this->traerDatosCambio();

    #### Generamos un string randomico para la nueva contraseña
    $data_email = array();
    $data_email["email_tipo"] = "comprar";
    $data_email["email_remitente"] = $this->config["smtp_user"];
    $data_email["email_destinatario"] = $correo;
    $data_email["email_asunto"] = "[BeerCoin] Proceso de compra";

    $message = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
<style type='text/css'>
/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

/* RESET STYLES */
img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

/* iOS BLUE LINKS */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .mobile-center {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}

/* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
div[style*='margin: 16px 0;'] { margin: 0 !important; }
</style>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; background-color: #eeeeee;' bgcolor='#eeeeee'>

<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td align='center' style='background-color: #eeeeee;' bgcolor='#eeeeee'>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600'>
        <tr>
        <td align='center' valign='top' width='600'>
        <![endif]-->
        <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width:600px;'>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' valign='top' style='font-size:0; padding: 35px;' bgcolor='#044767'>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600'>
                <tr>
                <td align='left' valign='top' width='300'>
                <![endif]-->
                <div style='display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:100px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;'>
                    <table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width:300px;'>
                        <tr>
                            <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 48px;' class='mobile-center'>
                                <h1 style='font-size: 36px; font-weight: 800; margin: 0; color: #ffffff;'>BeerCoins</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                <td align='right' width='300'>
                <![endif]-->
                <div style='display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:100px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;' class='mobile-hide'>
                    <table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width:300px;'>
                        <tr>
                            <td align='right' valign='top' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 48px;'>
                                <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' align='right'>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400;'>
                                            <p style='font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; color: #ffffff;'><a target='_blank' style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;'>Shop &nbsp;</a></p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px;'>
                                            <a target='_blank' style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;'><img src='https://www.tiindo-system.com/assets/img/email/shop.png' width='27' height='23' style='display: block; border: 0px;'/></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' style='padding: 35px 35px 20px 35px; background-color: #ffffff;' bgcolor='#ffffff'>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600'>
                <tr>
                <td align='center' valign='top' width='600'>
                <![endif]-->
                <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width:600px;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding-top: 25px;'>
                            <img src='https://www.tiindo-system.com/assets/img/email/check.png' width='125' height='120' style='display: block; border: 0px;' /><br>
                            <h2 style='font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 36px; color: #333333; margin: 0;'>
                                ¡Gracias por ordenar!
                            </h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding-top: 10px;'>
                            <p style='font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; color: #777777;'>
                                Gracias por ordenar en BeerCoins tu cafeteria favorita. La siguiente orden fue:
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='left' style='padding-top: 20px;'>
                            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width='75%' align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeee' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;'>
                                        Producto
                                    </td>
                                    <td width='25%' align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeee' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;'>
                                        Valor
                                    </td>
                                </tr>";
```

AQUI ES DONDE INICIA EL DOLOR DE CABEZA, la variable guardada en $message2

```
                            foreach($detalle as $d){
                                $message2 = "<tr>
                                <td width='75%' align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;'>"
                                        .$d->producto."
                                    </td>
                                    <td width='25%'' align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;''>
                                        ".$d->precio."
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>";
                            }
                            $message3 = "</table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='left' style='padding-top: 20px;'>
                            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width='75%' align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px; border-top: 3px solid #eeeeee; border-bottom: 3px solid #eeeeee;'>
                                        TOTAL
                                    </td>
                                    <td width='25%' align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px; border-top: 3px solid #eeeeee; border-bottom: 3px solid #eeeeee;'>
                                        $". $venta->row()->total ."
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <!-- LITMUS ATTRIBUTION -->

    <!-- END LITMUS ATTRIBUTION -->
</body>
</html>


    ";
    $data_email["email_mensaje"] = $message.$message2.$message3;
    $data_email["preparado"] = 1;
    $this->db->insert("dge_envio_email", $data_email);
    $responce = array(0 => false, 1 => "Envio programado exitosamente");
    return $responce;



}
```

ya intenté concatenarlos con =+ y me envia un 0 y lo intenté todo con el mismo nombre y tampoco me da registro. Esta es la solución más cercana que tuve, pero solo me muestra el primer dato traido del foreach

Comment: $message2 = "<tr>, reemplazalo por $message2 = message2 ."<tr>

Comment: El operador a+=b es para sumar números. Para sumar cadenas puedes hacer s.=t

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, pude solucionar, son cosas que se aprende todos los días

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así quedó el codigo y funcionando

```
public function compra($correo,$idventa){

    $detalle = $this->getDetalle($idventa);
    $venta = $this->db->get_where('venta',['id' =>$idventa]);
    // $cambio = $this->traerDatosCambio();

    #### Generamos un string randomico para la nueva contraseña
    $data_email = array();
    $data_email["email_tipo"] = "comprar";
    $data_email["email_remitente"] = $this->config["smtp_user"];
    $data_email["email_destinatario"] = $correo;
    $data_email["email_asunto"] = "[BeerCoin] Proceso de compra";
    $message2 = "";
    $message = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
<style type='text/css'>
/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

/* RESET STYLES */
img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

/* iOS BLUE LINKS */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mobile-hide {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .mobile-center {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}

/* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
div[style*='margin: 16px 0;'] { margin: 0 !important; }
</style>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; background-color: #eeeeee;' bgcolor='#eeeeee'>

<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td align='center' style='background-color: #eeeeee;' bgcolor='#eeeeee'>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600'>
        <tr>
        <td align='center' valign='top' width='600'>
        <![endif]-->
        <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width:600px;'>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' valign='top' style='font-size:0; padding: 35px;' bgcolor='#044767'>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600'>
                <tr>
                <td align='left' valign='top' width='300'>
                <![endif]-->
                <div style='display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:100px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;'>
                    <table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width:300px;'>
                        <tr>
                            <td align='left' valign='top' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 48px;' class='mobile-center'>
                                <h1 style='font-size: 36px; font-weight: 800; margin: 0; color: #ffffff;'>BeerCoins</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                <td align='right' width='300'>
                <![endif]-->
                <div style='display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:100px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;' class='mobile-hide'>
                    <table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width:300px;'>
                        <tr>
                            <td align='right' valign='top' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 48px;'>
                                <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' align='right'>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400;'>
                                            <p style='font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; margin: 0; color: #ffffff;'><a target='_blank' style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;'>Shop &nbsp;</a></p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px;'>
                                            <a target='_blank' style='color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;'><img src='https://www.tiindo-system.com/assets/img/email/shop.png' width='27' height='23' style='display: block; border: 0px;'/></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' style='padding: 35px 35px 20px 35px; background-color: #ffffff;' bgcolor='#ffffff'>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600'>
                <tr>
                <td align='center' valign='top' width='600'>
                <![endif]-->
                <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='max-width:600px;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding-top: 25px;'>
                            <img src='https://www.tiindo-system.com/assets/img/email/check.png' width='125' height='120' style='display: block; border: 0px;' /><br>
                            <h2 style='font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 36px; color: #333333; margin: 0;'>
                                ¡Gracias por ordenar!
                            </h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding-top: 10px;'>
                            <p style='font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; color: #777777;'>
                                Gracias por ordenar en BeerCoins tu cafeteria favorita. La siguiente orden fue:
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='left' style='padding-top: 20px;'>
                            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width='75%' align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeee' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;'>
                                        Producto
                                    </td>
                                    <td width='25%' align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeee' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;'>
                                        Valor
                                    </td>
                                </tr>";
                            foreach($detalle as $d){
                                $message2 =  $message2 . "<tr>
                                <td width='75%' align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;'>"
                                        .$d->producto."
                                    </td>
                                    <td width='25%'' align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;''>
                                        ".$d->precio."
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>";
                            }
                            $message3 = "</table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='left' style='padding-top: 20px;'>
                            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width='75%' align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px; border-top: 3px solid #eeeeee; border-bottom: 3px solid #eeeeee;'>
                                        TOTAL
                                    </td>
                                    <td width='25%' align='left' style='font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px; border-top: 3px solid #eeeeee; border-bottom: 3px solid #eeeeee;'>
                                        $". $venta->row()->total ."
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <!-- LITMUS ATTRIBUTION -->

    <!-- END LITMUS ATTRIBUTION -->
</body>
</html>


    ";
    $data_email["email_mensaje"] = $message.$message2.$message3;
    $data_email["preparado"] = 1;
    $this->db->insert("dge_envio_email", $data_email);
    $responce = array(0 => false, 1 => "Envio programado exitosamente");
    return $responce;



}
```